# Getting all orders that are from this month

Tags: c#, datetime, iqueryable, date-range

Here my current month:

```
model.SalesForMonth = orders.Where(o => o.DateOfPayment.Value.Month == DateTime.Now.Month)
                            .Select(o => o.Total)
                            .Sum();
```

This is not working as expect as it's also fetching orders that happened last year at the same month.

Sure I could compare year *and* month, but there must be a more expressive solution I'm not familiar with.

How can I do this cleanly using Linq? (*Not sure if relevant but `orders` is an IQueryable from Entity Framework*)

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way would be to create a start and end point:

```
// TODO: Consider what time zone you want to consider the current date in
var today = DateTime.Today;
var start = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
var end = start.AddMonths(1); // Exclusive end-point

var query = orders.Where(o => o.DateOfPayment.Value >= start &&
                              o.DateOfPayment.Value < end)
                        .Sum(o => o.Total)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want. You must compare year too to be sure that orders are from this year.
I think you can do it this way with linq:

```
    model.SalesForMonth = orders.Where(o => (o.DateOfPayment.Value.Month == DateTime.Now.Month
 && o.DateOfPayment.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year))
                                .Select(o => o.Total)
                                .Sum();
```

Comment: Your query method is not so simple as it requires date handling functions in the DB, as opposed to a simple range query (such as Jon's answer). Also, a simple index on the DateOfPayment column wouldn't be used with your query - two expression indexes to hold both the month and the year of this field would do the job, although I'm sure this is not a good way to go.